# Slide menu with paging control iOS

Tags: xcode, cocoa, user-experience

I want to create a Menu like the image with paging controls like the bottom of the buttons.

I dont know which controls use, some one can help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be one of the navigation windows.    The Amount of "dots" equals to amount if pages you'll have